# Domain issues in transformation of the coordinate representation of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, special-relativity

Start with a Manifold $M$ and define a function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. As usual, pick two charts $(U,x)$ and $(V,y)$ with $p \in U\cap V$ and $x:M \supset U \rightarrow x(U) \subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $(V,y)$ similarly. If we instead want to work with the coordinate description of $\phi : x(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\phi(x):= f\circ x^{-1}$. We can also define $\phi'(y)$ on the other chart by $f\circ y^{-1}$.

Now a coordinate transform is defined (in physics, at least) to be $\phi'(x) =(f\circ y^{-1} \circ x )(p)$. Now the usual course of action is to insert $x^{-1} \circ x$  after $f$ to get the result $\phi'(x) = (\phi\circ \Lambda^{-1})(x)$ where $\Lambda = y\circ x^{-1}$ is the chart transition map. This intuitively makes sense, but what is actually happening when we apply $y^{-1}$ to an element in $x(U)$? The function $y^{-1}$ is strictly defined from  $y(U) \rightarrow M$, it doesn't have anything to do with the space $x(U)$ except that they are both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What exactly is happening here? Am I just confusing myself? Is there some structure that I didn't include here that's assumed? For full context, I'm working in flat minkowski space where each point contains transition functions within the Poincare Lie group (Lorentz group + translations). Thanks.

Comment: When you have two overlapping charts, and you want to switch back and forth between them you can only look at points of $U\cap V$ in the manifold (or correspondingly $x[U\cap V] \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ and $y[U\cap V] \subset \Bbb{R}^n$), because otherwise the compositions $y\circ x^{-1}$ and $x\circ y^{-1}$ don't make sense. So, you have to restrict the function $\phi$ from $x[U]$ (it's original domain) to a slightly smaller domain $x[U\cap V]$. Similarly, $f\circ y^{-1}$ is originally defined on $y[V]$, but if you wish to transition between charts, you must look at $y[U\cap V]$.

Comment: Also, writing $\phi(x) = f\circ x^{-1}$ makes no sense. What you probably mean is $\phi = f \circ x^{-1}$. Similarly, $\phi' := f \circ y^{-1}$ (these are equalities of functions defined on $x[U]$ and $y[V]$ respectively).

Comment: I do understand that transition functions only occur on the overlap, I just forgot to mention the restriction when I introduced it. However, the remaining point about incorrect domain is precisely what I'm trying to clear up. In what way can physicists justify saying $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$ under a transformation of coordinates $\Lambda$? There is some implied transformation in the middle like (very sloppy notation incoming) $id_{\mathbb{R}^n} : x(U\cap V) \rightarrow y(U\cap V)$, but I see no reason why this would actually land in a point within $y(U\cap V)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me modify your notation slightly. Given a manifold $M$, a smooth function $f:M \to \Bbb{R}$, and two charts $(U,x), (V,y)$ with non-empty overlap, we can consider the following four functions:

- $f_{(x)}:= f\circ x^{-1} : x[U] \to \Bbb{R}$
- $f_{(y)} := f\circ y^{-1} : y[V] \to \Bbb{R}$
- $\Lambda := y \circ x^{-1}: x[U\cap V] \to y[U\cap V]$
- $\Lambda^{-1} = x\circ y^{-1}: y[U\cap V] \to x[U\cap V]$.

Intuitively, the function $f_{(x)}$ is "the function $f$ represented in $x$-coordinates", similarly for $f_{(y)}$, and the map $\Lambda$ is what physicists call "the transformation from $x$-coordinates to $y$-coordinates" (or something along those lines). With these definitions, it is easily seen that
\begin{align}
f_{(x)} &= f_{(y)} \circ \Lambda \quad \text{and} \quad f_{(y)} = f_{(x)} \circ \Lambda^{-1}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}

That's all you really need to know (I believe physicists refer to these equations as the "transformation law for scalar fields" or something like that). If you write this out in full, it simply says
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
f\circ x^{-1} &= (f\circ y^{-1}) \circ (y\circ x^{-1}) \\\\
f\circ y^{-1} &= (f\circ x^{-1}) \circ (x\circ y^{-1})
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So, the only way to get from $x[U\cap V]$ to $y[U\cap V]$ is through the transition map $\Lambda := y \circ x^{-1}$.

Comment: @Nick Cox If this still doesn't clarify matters then you'll have to provide an explicit example of something an author has written which is confusing you (I kind of understand your struggle because I also have this issue when reading physics sometimes, but currently I'm not sure what exactly the issue is, because you're right in saying that there's no way to apply consider $y^{-1}\circ x$, because the domains don't even match up, but I doubt an author actually said something which suggests it is possible)

Comment: I am primarily referring to equation 1.26 in [these notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf). From what I understand, their $\phi$ is the same as your $f_{(x)}$ and $\phi'$ is $f_{(y)}$. This would mean that $\phi'(x)$ looks like $f_{(y)}\circ x$ which leads to the clash. It makes sense as you said it, do you know any way to reconcile that explanation with this notation? There is some hand-wavy argument that the function itself is transformed. Thanks again.

Comment: @NickCox I don't think they're referring to charts at all. This is one of those situations I think it is much clearer to think more abstractly first then specialize. Suppose we have two manifolds $M,N$, a smooth function $\phi:M\to\Bbb{R}$ (a "scalar field"), and suppose we have a diffeomorphism $\Lambda:M \to N$. Now, how can we get a scalar field on the manifold $N$? Well the most obvious thing to do is consider $\phi' := \phi \circ \Lambda^{-1} : N \to \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: So, in those notes, when they write $\phi(x)$, what is meant is that $x\in M$ is a point in the manifold and $\phi(x)$ really is the value of the function when evaluated at that particular point in the manifold $M$. It is unfortunate that they use the notation $\phi(x) \to \phi'(x) = \phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$, because the $x$ in $\phi(x)$ lives in the manifold $M$ while the $x$ in $\phi'(x)$ lives in the manifold $N$, so it's a confusing double usage of the letter $x$. But as I mentioned above, what they're instructing you to do is to consider the function $\phi \circ \Lambda^{-1}:N \to \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: We can also state this in another way: given a diffeomorphism $\Lambda:M \to N$, it induces a map $T_{\Lambda}: C^{\infty}(M, \Bbb{R}) \to C^{\infty}(N,\Bbb{R})$ defined as
$T_{\Lambda}(\phi) := \phi \circ \Lambda^{-1}$
(and you can easily check $T_{\Lambda}$ is a bijection). Now you may want to specialize to the case where $N=M$. Then, $\Lambda:M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism and you get an induced map $\phi':= \phi\circ \Lambda^{-1} :M \to \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Though I have to admit, that one thing which is confusing to me is their use of Lorentz transformations as a map on the spacetime manifold $M$, because I always learnt that Lorentz transformations are isomorphisms of the tangent spaces (though I guess they're doing this because if you assume $M$ itself is a vector space then you can canonically identify it with each of its tangent spaces)

Comment: Okay, I think I was sticking too hard to the clear distinction between a manifold and its coordinate charts. I think the key part I was missing is that flat Minkowski space actually has a [global coordinate system](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spacetime). Thus it makes sense to think of $\phi$ as being defined on points directly on the manifold.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the chart picture also starts to make more sense considering only charts which cover the entire manifold. Then we really can define a natural identity map that brings coordinates from one copy of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to another.

Comment: @NickCox It's certainly true that every vector space has a global chart (eg $\Bbb{R}^3, \Bbb{R}^4$ etc), but I think it is a very good idea (atleast conceptually) to keep a very clear distinction between a manifold and the chart representations of various objects (because in GR you don't usually have global charts)